# Spresense SDK IDE開発環境（Mac）でのビルド・書き込み時のエラーについて

Tags: macos, spresense, vscode, zsh

macOS Catalina Version 10.15.6
Spresense SDK Version 2.0.1
Visual Studio Code Version 1.48.2
Spresense VSCode IDE Version 1.2.0

上記環境にて [Spresense SDKスタートガイド（IDE）](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html) に従ってサンプルアプリを作成し、ビルド・書き込み時に下記エラーが出てしまい、書き込みが失敗しました。

```
zsh:1: no matches found: out/worker/*

zsh:1: no matches found: out/worker/*

The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'cd "/Users/itadera/Documents/devel/test";if [ "echo out/worker/*" != "out/worker/*" ]; then /Users/itadera/Documents/devel/spresense/sdk/tools/flash.sh -w -c /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART -b 115200 out/worker/*; fi;'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

調べたところ、VS Codeで既定シェルの選択で「zsh」を選んだ場合、上記エラーが発生していることが確認しました。シェルを「bash」に切り替えたら、問題なくビルド・書き込みが進みました。

インターネット上では、zsh環境で特定のコマンド（glob表現が含まれるもの）を実行する際、同じ「no matches found」エラーが発生する報告があります。

[zshで no match found のときの解決策 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/nisaji/items/f9eede2164a74bc08db7)

そのため、前述リンクにて記載された対策で対応してみましたが、ターミナルで `echo out/worker/*` を実行したらエラーが出なくなりましたが、「ビルド・書き込み」を実行する際、同じエラーが出てしまいました。

現状では、ビルド・書き込みを行うためにはbashに切り替えるしかなさそうだと思いますが、新macOS Catalina のシェルが zsh を標準にしているため、zsh環境でもビルド・書き込みができるような対策が欲しく、質問をさせていただきます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

ここを見つけた他の人のために、解決法を書いておきます。

VS Code を開いて「File」→「Settings」を開き `terminal.integrated.shell` で検索します。そして Mac のシェルを `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash"` に変更します。

すると Spresense ボードに対する Build & Flash で書き込みが成功するようになるはずです。

---

※この回答は元々英語で投稿されたものに対して日本語訳がつけられました。以下原文です。

For others finding this issue, here's how to resolve it:

In VS Code, open File > Settings > and search for `terminal.integrated.shell` then change your Mac shell to `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash"`

Now, when you Build & Flash to the Spresense board the flash will succeed.