# SpresenseにVSCodeを使って書き込む際にエラーになる

Tags: spresense

表題のようにSpresenseにVSCodeからプログラムを書き込もうとするとエラーになります。
やり方は [Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html) のように行っています。

CLI環境ではうまくいっておりますので、何かしらの設定がおかしいのだと思うのですが、見当がつかない状態となっております。
何か思い当たる点等ありましたらご教示いただきたく思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

環境 : macOS Big Sur

エラー内容 :

```
-前半略-
Generating: nuttx.spk
File nuttx.spk is successfully created.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task in folder mypro: cd "/Users/xxx/WorkSpace/Projects/mypro";if [ "`echo out/worker/*`" != "out/worker/*" ]; then /Users/xxx/WorkSpace/Projects/spresense/sdk/tools/flash.sh -w -c /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART -b 115200 out/worker/*; fi; <

zsh:1: no matches found: out/worker/*
zsh:1: no matches found: out/worker/*
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'cd "/Users/xxx/WorkSpace/Projects/mypro";if [ "`echo out/worker/*`" != "out/worker/*" ]; then /Users/xxx/WorkSpace/Projects/spresense/sdk/tools/flash.sh -w -c /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART -b 115200 out/worker/*; fi;'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70316/spresense-sdk-ide開発環境-mac-でのビルド-書き込み時のエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70316/spresense-sdk-ide%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83-mac-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89-%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6) にある通り、`"terminal.integrated.shell"` を `"/bin/bash"` に変更してみてください。